# Remove the (sub)section number from figures in LaTeX

Tags: latex, figure

I'm using overleaf for my thesis and I would like some help.

(document class=report)

I am using chapters, sections, and subsections. My tables are named after the chapter and increment with every table (e.g. 5.1 and 5.2 for two tables in Chapter 5). My figures are named after the chapter, including section number and subsection (e.g. a figure in Chapter 5, section 3 is called 5.3.1, even though it is the first figure in Chapter 5). I want the section and subsection number removed from my figure names and have the same counting as for the tables. Can you please help? Thanks!

Comment: please make a [mre]

Answer (score 4):

I already found the answer (by trial-and-error):

simply add the following code to the main.tex:

```
\counterwithout{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}
```

Comment: Been looking for this for hours now, please mark it as solved.